# Spring Form Validation Implementation

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

My question is, what is the use of the **`springForm:form tag`**?

Why the prefix `springform` ??

Why can't I use my usual `form` tag??

Can someone tell me the difference?

I visited [this](http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-validation-example-mvc-validator) link, but I'm unable to understand. Can someone explain it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A P it is just a `custom tag reference`.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="springForm" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

In above line one should informing that I am going to use spring tag using **prefix** `springForm` so that you will avail all spring tags support in your jsp.

And you can use normal `form`, but you won't avail the functionalities of spring tags.

Example `path` attribute is not supported in normal form,but it is supported in spring,so no need to map(binding),`Spring` will automatically map the value to mentioned path variable.

Comment: to I am using the springForm tag to get the benefit of binging values? Is there any other advantage of this tag over my form tag?

Comment: May be yes, but as i mentioned binding using path attribute is the main purpose of springForm tag and to show form errors..

Comment: Thanks a lot Prasanna. Last question : If I want to use this tag in a spring boot project, I do it in the same way as I do in my simple mvc project??Or is there some different way to do it in boot?

Comment: I mean, I declare it like <%@ taglib prefix="springForm" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%> and then I use it.

Comment: Does the same apply in spring boot?

Comment: @AP I m not sure about that(I m not expert in spring boot so)..i ll check it,if i come to know i ll post here